# Connect circle nodes of differect groups force-layouts with lines

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have created 3 groups of circles each in different force layout:

```
(function () {
    /****** Functions *******
     ************************/
    var rand = function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    /****** Variables *******
     ************************/
    var i,
        color,
        width  = 400,
        height = 400,
        forces = [],
        coords,
        _linksData, _nodesData,
        mainContainer;

    /** Coordinates of groups **/
    coords = [
        [0, 0],
        [width, 0],
        [width * 2, 0],
    ];

    color = d3.scale.category10();

    /****** Main SVG container *******
     *********************************/
    mainContainer = d3.select("#main-container").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1165)
        .attr("height", 650)
        .append("g");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        forces[i] = d3.layout.force();

        (function () {
            /****** Generate Random Data for one Group *******
             *************************************************/

            /** Random amount of circles with random radius **/
            _nodesData = d3.range(rand(25, 45)).map(function (d, i) {
                return {
                    id     : i,
                    radius : rand(6, 18)
                }
            });

            /**
             Add children to group with 0 radius in order to have d3
             position it in center and put all other circles in its orbit
             **/
            _nodesData.push({
                children : d3.range(_nodesData.length),
                radius   : 0
            });

            /** Add links **/
            _linksData = d3.layout.tree().links(_nodesData);


            /****** Create Group Container *******
             *************************************/
            var groupContainer = mainContainer.append("g")
                .attr('class', 'group')
                .attr('id', 'group' + i)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + coords[i][0] + ',' + coords[i][1] + ')')
                .on('mouseenter', function () {
                    var index = d3.select(this).attr('id').replace('group', '');
                    // console.log(index);
                    forces[index].alpha(.25);
                });

            var nodesObjects = groupContainer.selectAll(".node");
            var linksObjects = groupContainer.selectAll(".link")

            /****** Force Layout ******/
            forces[i].linkDistance(function () {
                    return rand(110, 130)
                })
                .charge(function () {
                    return -rand(150, 200)
                })
                .gravity(0.1 + 1 / rand(10, 50))
                .size([width, height])
                .on("tick", tick)
                .nodes(_nodesData)
                .links(_linksData)
                .start();

            /****** links ******/
            // linksObjects = linksObjects.data(_linksData)
            //     .enter()
            //     .append("line").attr('class', 'link')
            //
            // ;

            /****** Create nodes ******/
            nodesObjects = nodesObjects.data(_nodesData, function (d) {
                    return d.id;
                })
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .on('mouseover', function () {
                    d3.select(this).moveToFront();
                });


            /****** Create circles ******/
            nodesObjects.append("circle")
                .attr("r", function (d) {
                    return d.radius;
                }).style("fill", color(i));


            function tick() {
                linksObjects.attr({
                    x1 : function (d) {
                        return d.source.x;
                    },
                    y1 : function (d) {
                        return d.source.y;
                    },
                    x2 : function (d) {
                        return d.target.x;
                    },
                    y2 : function (d) {
                        return d.target.y;
                    }
                });

                nodesObjects.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            }

        })();
    }
}())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/h69wqvcy/2/

Result:
[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to add lines connecting circles and keep circles on its positions?
[image]

Clarification: lines should be connected to circles, i.e. update their positions when circles moves

http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrychuba/h69wqvcy/2/

**UPDATE**

It was achieved by adding lines layout and updating their positions on tick event

Comment: Absolutely. I would give each line a class that you can derive from the data of the source and target node that uniquely identifies it so that it can be selected knowing just the source or target. Then all you need is do exactly that and update the coordinates on either end in the `tick` handler function of the respective force layout.

Comment: That's exactly what I just did, which solved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question to prevent circles from moving:

You can call `force.alpha(0)` to stop the movement after awhile and then `resume()` the layout on `mouseout`. Maybe this can work for you depending on what you want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/h69wqvcy/3/

```
            var groupContainer = mainContainer.append("g")
                .attr('class', 'group')
                .attr('id', 'group' + i)
                .attr('transform',
                'translate(' + coords[i][0] + ',' + coords[i][1] + ')')
                .on('mouseenter', function () {
                    var index = d3.select(this).attr('id').replace('group', '');
                    // console.log(index);
                    forces[index].alpha(0.25);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        forces[index].alpha(0);
                    }, 1000);
                })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                    var index = d3.select(this).attr('id').replace('group', '');
                    // console.log(index);
                    forces[index].resume();
                });
```

You should alse clear the timeout if mouseout occurs before the timeout expires.

Comment: I don't think that this is the question -- OP is asking how to update the positions of the lines as the circles move.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the question. It would be nice if the OP clarifies the question once again.