# Bigraph visualization with D3 force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm trying to implement a custom viz of Bigraphs (something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHfc4.png)). In this kind of graph the nodes can contains other nodes to visualize the hierarchy between nodes. I'm trying to realize that visualization and I've found this useful example: http://jsfiddle.net/hznquL19/ but I have some doubts:

1. I don't know the deep of my trees (the data can vary and my script must render different kind of bigraphs) so i don't know how many force layout I must create: there's a way to create a number of force layout on a fly?
2. Should I create for every layout a tick function with appropriate displacement like in the example fiddle?

   ```
   function outerTick (e) {outerNodes.attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});}
   function innerAtick (e) {innerAnodes.attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + (d.x - 20) + "," + (d.y - 20) + ")";});}
   function innerBtick (e) {innerBnodes.attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + (d.x - 20) + "," + (d.y - 20) + ")";});}
   ```
3. Can I create connection between nodes that owns to different force layout?

Thank you

**EDIT**

For now I've a solution for question 1 & 2

1. I create a force layout who contains only the roots of the trees and then I create a force layout for every sets of childs of every root. Then i repeat the process for every set of child nodes of the nodes with depth = 1 and so on.
2. Every force layout will have a tick function. No problem with the displacement that is handled by a correct implementation of forces (gravity center and repulsion between nodes)

For the question 3 this [Connect circle nodes of differect groups force-layouts with lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675455/connect-circle-nodes-of-differect-groups-force-layouts-with-lines) it's a good starting point but I can't figure out How can I create Bézier links with this technique and how to use the package D3-hypergraph for the creation of hypergraph connection.

Comment: Hi, any follow up to this project?

Comment: @AustinLopez take a look to my implementation here: https://github.com/AndreaSimeone/Bigraph-Visualization